# Setting LinearLayout in different screen size

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` which is made programmatically like this:

```
listLinear=new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams listParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
listLinear.setLayoutParams(listParam);
```

80 is my `listLinear` width. I want my `LinearLayout` width to be 80. My `LinearLayout` looks perfectly as I want in 4.5 inch screen but when I test it in 5 inch display it just shrinks and looks small in size.

Why is it happening?

Comment: You shouldn't have to deal with physical screen size. Do it the `dp` way or 'layout_weight' way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the constructor of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` expects the width/height in pixels.

For your layout to look the same on all screen sizes, you should define its width in *dip* (density-independent pixels).

Something like this should work:

```
listLinear = new LinearLayout(this);

int widthDp = 50; // desired width in dp, adjust this as you'd like

// converting dp to pixels
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int widthPx = Math.round(
    widthDp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams listParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthPx,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

listLinear.setLayoutParams(listParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

after setcontentview
use this code

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
getWindow().setLayout((int) (width), (int) (height * .2));
```

Comment: I am using this code in service class because the linearlayout is attached to windowmanager how can i use getwindowmanager() in service class

Comment: in service class use a constructor and call that main activity context there.